# What is the best way to program the path of a bullet?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flashdevelop

I am playing around with ActionScript 3 and trying to build a very simple prototype for a video game (top-down action/shooter) and realized that handling bullets is a little bit more challenging than I originally imagined.

In order to get a fairly decent "flight" of the bullet between the character and the target, I ended up using a highly modified version of [Bresenham's Line Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) to determine the flight path of the bullet and then merely draw a tiny flash.geom.Rectangle object at the appropriate place on that "flight path" during the draw-frame stage of my application.

I haven't noticed any real problems, but I just can't imagine this being the best way to handle bullets in a Flash game. I imagine that once there are multiple enemy players on the screen and lots of bullets flying around (especially once I code in automatic weapons) that things could come grinding to a halt.

What am I missing here? I'm not really a game developer and so most of the things I'm doing I've just "made up" on the spot, but I can't figure out how to effectively handle bullets in Flash.

**EDIT**: As requested, here is "my" Bresenham code. I say "my" in quotes, because I basically ripped this from somewhere on the internet. My changes to the algorithm basically involve the lines at the bottom. The original implementation would find the path from player character to the target, except that every once in a while (and I wasted a little bit of time trying to figure this out but never got anywhere) it will generate the path from the target to the player. To "fix" this, I ended up just checking the first X/Y values from the path array and reversing the array if those values didn't match the X/Y values of my player character.

```
public function bresenham(fromX:int, fromY:int, toX:int, toY:int, value:int):Array
{
    // store the character's location
    var orig_x:int = fromX;
    var orig_y:int = fromY;

    var error:int;
    var bullet_path:Array = new Array;

    var dx:int = toX - fromX;
    var dy:int = toY - fromY;
    var yi:int = 1;
    if ( dx < dy ) {
        // swap end points
        fromX ^= toX; toX ^= fromX; fromX ^= toX;
        fromY ^= toY; toY ^= fromY; fromY ^= toY;
    }

    if ( dx < 0 ) {
        dx = -dx;
        yi = -yi;
    }
    if ( dy < 0 ) {
        dy = -dy;
        yi = -yi;
    }
    if ( dy > dx ) {
        error = -( dy >> 1 );
        for ( ; toY < fromY; toY++ ) {
            bullet_path.push( { 'x' : toX, 'y': toY } );
            error += dx;
            if ( error > 0 ) {
                toX   += yi;
                error -= dy;
            }
        }
    } else {
        error = -(dx >> 1);
        for ( ; fromX < toX; fromX++ ) {
            bullet_path.push( { 'x' : fromX, 'y': fromY } );
            error += dy;
            if ( error > 0 ) {
                fromY += yi;
                error -= dx;
            }
        }
    }
    // reverse the bullet path if it was generated from target to player.
    if ( bullet_path[0].x != orig_x && bullet_path[0].y != orig_y ) {
        return bullet_path.reverse();
    }
    return bullet_path;
}
```

Comment: do you consider gravity with the bullet path?

Comment: See if your method is even a problem, set it up so it fires 40  bullets at a time in a spread with no delay per shot. keep increasing the bullets per frame if it still runs fast. If the number is at an acceptable amount then you are fine.

Comment: @John: Not right now. This is a very simplistic 2D top-down demo. I just want the bullet to leave my character and head towards the target on a fairly straight line.

Comment: @AttackingHobo: I think you might be on to something here. I just turned on "machine gun" mode and watched my FPS while I spat out about 500 bullets and couldn't find a horrible degredation of performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you post your implementation (of Bresenham's) code here? I would like to make a benchmark test if my implementation is faster :D...

Weird thing - I DID do a benchmark comparing my implementation with AS3.0's native *Graphics.drawLine()*... It was LITERALLY 5 to 10 times faster. It is even anti-aliased, but I guess nativity here does the thing.

But anyway - as long as the bullets... Let's say MISSILES (bullets, rockets, lasers...) here aren't anything slowly moving, big which is supposed to look good too (not just line), use **MovieClip**, or even better **Sprite** when no animation is needed. Everywhere else use *Graphics.drawLine()*.

Also, for hit-testing with the lines, and finding the points to draw the lines to (not **Sprites**), you would have a range of that bullet (if infinite, use something like *Stage.width*, or *Stage.height* if it's bigger), where it can still hit. Then you would also have its angle. If it is along X or Y axes, it is fairly easy to get the points of the line. For the different ones, use *Point.polar(range, angle)* [[liveDocs]](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/geom/Point.html#polar()), to which you add the original position of that bullet.

Hit-testing would be done with *Point.interpolate()* [[liveDocs]](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/geom/Point.html#interpolate()). Point 1 would be the original position / start point, the second would be the point that you got from *Point.polar()*. Finally, the last param must be the distance from start (no need for *Math.atan2()* here - just increment this value each frame by the bullet's speed) divided by the distance between start and end points (again, no *Math.atan2()* - just the "range". This *Point.interpolate()* would give you a point, that you will finally use with each possible target for the bullet (either loop through all, or, for performance, check if the X and Y distances are smaller or equal to their width and height) - *target.hitTestPoint(interX, interY, true)* [[liveDocs]](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#hitTestPoint()).

Comment: See, that is exactly what I was worried about. I know my Bresenham algorithm works fairly well and it's super-fast, but I was afraid that there was a "Graphics.drawLine()" and I just didn't know about it. Thank you. I didn't know about any of those methods (Point.polar(), Point.interpolate(), etc). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Before you try to find a faster method, see if your code is a bottleneck in the first place.**

Keep increasing the number of objects fired per frame until you see unacceptable frames per second.

You should also check out GameDev.Stackexchange.com, as a lot of people there are more qualified to answer Game Dev questions.

Comment: I turned my gun into a machine gun that fired roughly 3 or 4 new Bullet rectangles every frame and it slowed down, but not enough that would be a problem (considering there were probably 10,000 Rectangle objects on the stage at the time). I'm going to try using the Graphics.drawLine() method that Aurel300 recommended and see if that is any better. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

No matter what you do, too many actors on the stage will degrade performance. I would personally try to create symbol instances as movieClips and move them along a path, deleting them when they come into contact with a target. (Doing it this way also gives  you collision detection, which will be important if the targets can move out of the way. If a collision is detected the bullet can play its "explosion" scene, etc.)

Comment: No - you don't really get it... He's trying to use Bresenham's line algorithm which is VERY fast. But you suggest MovieClip for every... line on a screen -.- Really, that would be 100x slower.

Comment: Yeah. Bresenham's Algo seems to be extremely fast at computing the path of the bullet. It's just that it's a lot of really ugly code and I wasn't sure if this is how other people are doing things like this.

I don't want to be the only one computing bullet trajectories and flight paths manually when everyone else on the planet is using a hack like creating a flash.geom.Rectangle segment between two points and doing something like changing the border color or something. Just wanted to make sure I wasn't going too far off track. :/

Comment: Also, I don't even know what a movieClip is at this stage. I'm just trying to handle my input and have a little dude walk around the screen shooting at randomly generated bad-guy rectangles... :D

Comment: Honestly, if you want to make fast games, you will have no MovieClips actually on the stage when the game is running. copyPixels is so much faster compared to MovieClips.

Answer (score 0):

Determine the distance the bullet should move in each frame once and let it go. If each bullet knows how far it should move on its x and y properties per frame, you don't need to calculate it again and the bullet will fly straight. If your using Bresenham's Line Algorithm every time the bullet moves, you are doing to much work. Just make sure the movement in x and y is stored as a Number otherwise the bullet wont end up where it should.

Comment: I only generate the Bresenham path once per "fire" event. Doesn't seem to have any negative side-effects.